# Hook isn't invoked

Tags: 7, hooks

I try to add some fields to content type through this hook as it done in node_example module in Drupal 7 examples but it's not even invoked. What can be wrong?

```
function education_node_type_insert($content_type){
            $fields = _anketa_installed_fields();
            foreach($fields as $field){
                field_create_field($field);
            }

            $instances = _anketa_installed_instances();
            foreach($instances as $instance){
                $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
                $instance['bundle'] = 'anketa';
                field_create_field($instance);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your custom module is enabled? Did you clear cache after you added the implementation of hook_node_type_insert?

Comment: Yes, I even tried to disable and enable it back several times. Same thing with clearing cache

Comment: Out of curiosity what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just trying to create content type and add fields to it. In node_example example from drupal.org it works but in my case - doesn't. Just can't figure out why.

Comment: Why not use the Features module to export your field definition?

Comment: You mean create in drupal and then export it somehow?

Comment: Yes, first configure all your fields as you want it. Then from the Features UI you can choose what fields, content types etc you want to export then it will create a module with the chosen definitions for you. There is a detailed guide here for example http://joshwaihi.com/node/4#.Ufp72OF9kak

Comment: Great! The features module is very powerful, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This hook will only get called when [node_type_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_save/7) is called - ie. when a new node type is saved to the database.

Comment: So the type should be saved in hook_install anyway?